# SublimeREPL starts lein with wrong Java

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I have a leiningen project which works fine when run from the command line. I try to run it from Sublime Text 2 with SublimeREPL but leiningen gets started with java 1.6 instead of 1.7:

```
(System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.6.0_29"
```

The same from the command line

```
lein repl
user=> (System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.7.0_40"
```

I have my PATH, JAVA_HOME and SublimeREPL.sublime-settings are all configured to Java 7. I work on OS X 10.8.5. Where should I look?

Comment: I edited SublimeREPL.sublime-settings and added a variable to default_extend_env: "LEIN_JAVA_CMD" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java". Leiningen stil starts java 1.6.

Comment: Actually defining LEIN_JAVA_CMD in SublimeREPL.sublime-settings *did* fix the problem. SublimREPL was starting an aloder Java, I still don't understand the exact reason.